# How to display eclipse project type

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

In Eclipse IDE there are icons to display the project type, but I can't find a text description. I would expect right click -> properties to show this info but according to this all projects are of type "project" (even if they are a java project, or maven project etc.)

Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=509053), you won't find the text description in Eclipse GUI.

One way is to go to the root folder of your project, open the file named `.project` and check the elements in the tag `<natures></natures>`.

But don't worry about that, these icons are often explicit.

Comment: sorry, I gotta down vote this answer. Even seeing <natures> and knowing that the icons are explicit, this answer still does not explain how to interpret the values within the <natures> tag or what the meaning of each icon is. The questioner wants to know what wizard was used to create the project... there a a number of different wizards that all produce a Java project icon.

Comment: @PMorganCA Well I you are able to give a better answer, I will happilly delete mine and upvote yours.