# Is there a way to easily determine project types in Eclipse visually?

Tags: eclipse

I have in my package and project explorers a large number of projects.  These projects are of mixed type.  Is there a way I can visually tell, say, which of these projects are python or which of these are java or ...  So I notice if you open a project there is a small icon which tells you what type it is, but I cannot keep all my projects open.  Maybe there is a filter which only displays projects of type x?

I see a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675093/how-to-display-eclipse-project-type) which is very minimally tangential to mine but which requires greater effort to actually probe each project for its type.

Comment: Oh and one approach I have used in the past is to actually put Java or Python or whatever in the project name, but there has to be something better

Comment: So I have seen two different working set answers which are a good idea.  But are these solutions "do this before your workspace gets out of control?" or can I create working sets not knowing the types of each project offhand?  So like can you create working set of all java projects automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When open you will get an icon decorator, a small "J" in top left corner for Java projects. Something similar should be present for Python projects as well. But as you pointed out, these are only seen when the project is open. Here are some alternatives:

1. Keep separate workspaces. Have one workspace for Java development where you only import the java projects, and a separate for all Python projects. This works well unless you very often work with several projects of different natures at the same time.
2. Use working sets. You can sort projects into several working sets, that will help you to organize projects according to their natures. Then set Package explorer to show Working sets as top level element. See the view menu in package explorer view. [See this](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/categorise-projects-package).
3. Use [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/). Mylyn will enable a task focused view that will only show your projects relevant to the current task. If you are working against a task repository such as Jira or Bugzilla, then this is very effective and I strongly recommend you try it out.

I would suggest alternative 2 + 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify project type by the project type decorator icons in the project explorer.
In the picture shown below.

[image]

You can see **M** letter indicate maven project type. **J** letter Indicates Java project type similarly you can find indicator for C, C++, Python etc projects.

Project having no letter is know as General project.

To filter different projects you can use "Working sets". [See here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-working-set-and-how-do-i-use-it.html)

Check this [plugin](http://taggerplugin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The display is like that if the project is open, but having 100 projects open at once isn't a very memory efficient.

Comment: You can keep open any number of project. No problem. Note that closed projects are not included in search scope. You can use **collapse icon** in the project explorer to quickly view all projects

Comment: If I have too many projects open, Eclipse will surely crash.  At least for my projects that is the case.